# call gnuplot via fork and pipe and update plot

Tags: c++, c, pipe, fork, gnuplot

I want to do some realtime-plots during a simulation. For this, i would like to use octave or gnuplot. My current approach is to use a frontend to gnuplot, feedgnuplot, which fits actually very well.

The Simulation is written in C++, so i thought about forking (new process for feedgnuplot) and piping the relevant data to feedgnuplot.

The problem i have is that the output is only visible after the simulation.
But i want to see the plot updated during simulation.

Here is a MWE:

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main()
{
    FILE* stream = popen("feedgnuplot", "w");

    for(int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
    {
        fprintf(stream, "%d\n", i * i);
        fflush(stream);
        sleep(1);
    }
}
```

The program stops after 10 secons, showing the plot.

When using `feedgnuplot` directly in the shell, everything works as expected.
(That is, newly added data is plotted without the need to end the process)

What am i doing wrong? I think i lack some understanding of how popen really works.

Answer (score 0):

First, let's write a fake feedgnuplot.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    char *buf = NULL;
    size_t n = 0;

    while (getline (&buf, &n, stdin) != -1) {
        printf ("%s", buf);
    }

    free (buf);
    return 0;
}
```

With this, your code works, i.e. the lines are printed as they arrive.

I suspect the problem lies in the way your feedgnuplot program reads incoming data. You should show the relevant part of that code.

If I had to take a guess, you probably need to add

```
setvbuf (stdin, NULL, _IOLBF, 0);
```

in feedgnuplot before you start to read from stdin.

That is because by default, when stdin corresponds to a terminal it is line buffered, whereas when it corresponds to a pipe it is fully buffered. The code above makes stdin line buffered no matter what so there should be no difference between reading from a terminal or a pipe.

Comment: Thank you! I found a way to make feedgnuplot (a program not written by me) behave the way i want: `... | feedgnuplot --stream`.